# Getting streaming responses using R, httr2, and WebSocket

Tags: r, websocket, httr2

I'm trying use R package `httr2` to set up a connection for streaming stock prices. My provider uses WebSocket. I have read documentation and searched high and low, but can't get it to work, following the API [documentation](https://www.developer.saxo/openapi/learn/streaming) and httr2 [documentation](https://httr2.r-lib.org/reference/req_stream.html).

When I do:

```
library(httr2)
library(dplyr)

token <- paste("BEARER", "mytoken")
url <- paste0("http://streaming.saxobank.com/sim/openapi/streamingws/connect?contextId=4UpfnD4ycH&authorization=", token)
req <- request(url)

show_bytes <- function(x) {
  cat("Got ", length(x), " bytes\n", sep = "")
  TRUE
}

r <- req %>% req_stream(show_bytes)
```

I get a 400 error.

I suspect that either I'm approacing this the wrong way, or `http2` doesn't support WebSocket?

Comment: Have you tried the `websocket` package? `httpuv` supports websockets, and `httr2` suggests `httpuv`, but I don't know to what degree it may use websockets; [I can't find mention of the word "websockets" in the httr2 repo](https://github.com/r-lib/httr2/search?q=websockets), so perhaps not?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I tried the websocket package, couldn't get it to work with the API ressource I want to consume